# Good hash function for cache memory?

Tags: c, algorithm, caching, hash, hashcode

I would like to implement a hash function that goes into a cache memory. Initially, I have 20 bits of input and I need to hash this input into 7 bits.

My cache is 128x4.

I have tried different hash functions, but the results were not very good (I get 60% hit rate). I was thinking of using the MD5 algorithm, but maybe something is better. I read an implementation of MD5 online, but I did not get it.

Comment: This isn't clear, what do you mean by a "hash function that goes into a cache memory"?

Comment: the output of the hash function is the index for a cache memory.

Comment: Check out @Mdlg answer in SO "Can one construct a “good” hash function using CRC32C as a base".  I have had reasonable success with using CRCs for a hash.

Comment: MD5 is no good idea, you want a hash function that can be comuted fast, computing MD5 is quite complex and meant to be used in cryptographic context.

Comment: Could you post more parameters?  I take it `x4` is four-way set associative, but how big is a cache line?  Will you be implementing this in hardware?  What kind of test patterns are you using?  Is this cache for a special application, or a general-purpose CPU cache?

Comment: This might be too simple or stupid, but what about just taking the low 7 bits of the input 20 bits and using these for your cache index? Do you need a hash? Are the input low 7 bits not evenly distributed?

Comment: @WayneUroda, that is a common approach, and it may be totally appropriate for the OP's situation.  Generally what can happen when you do this is that specific access patterns (often showing up in image-processing operations) get an exceptionally high rate of cache alias hits which causes thrashing.  There can also be some ugly interaction with SDRAM banks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a perfectly distributed hash could actually be undesirable, here.  It offers the possibility of mapping nearby addresses into the same set.

Perhaps what you want to do is hash 17 bits down to 4, and map the three low-order bits straight through so as to guarantee a minimum distance between instances of the same set.